# Accessing an Applescript from 2 different menus produces different results. Why?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, applescript, osx-yosemite

I've got an application that has an embedded Script menu for running Applescripts. However, if you try to run scripts with certain functions (mostly UI related) they won't work unless you run them from the System script menu (in menu bar).

For example, if in theApplication you say :

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "theApp" to get all windows
```

it will return an empty list if run from the program's script menu, but 2 if run from the system script menu. I've also tried:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "theApp" 
        set allElements to UI elements
        display dialog (count of allElements)
    end tell
end tell
-- returns 2 when run from System script menu but 0 when run from within theApp.
```

Also if you run from the Script Editor it will work fine. GUI scripting is enabled for the application in System Preferences, so I'm curious as to why this is happening, and any workarounds for it (other than run the script from the System Script menu)? The Dictionary shows Standard Suite so it should have access to windows...

Any ideas?

Comment: One problem could be with the Script Menu implementation of "theApp". Since you're not disclosing what theApp is, I assumed its something you wrote?   When you launch from each different location, that domain is different, so UI info will innately be different. Try adding a: tell app "theApp" to activate    line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't provisioned the app in question to use assistive devices.

You should really open System Preferences, then click the button for "Security", then unlock, and click the button for Assitive Devices, (the blue icon with a white man), then drag your app onto it (reveal your app from its Dock menu), and permit it to control your machine, remember to lock the pane afterwards.

I can not guaranttee this to work, but it is certainly worth a try.

Comment: That's what I meant by "Gui scripting is enabled..." I just didn't clarify. In fact I've turned it off then back on again for the app just to reset it... still doesn't work.

Comment: I'd rather address the Vendor of the app with that then, because if you add or delete elements of the script menu, then that shouldn't be perceived as any changes done to the app, that is at least how I understand it. Because if you "enable gui scripting", then that should work, until you change the app.